# WinSCP capabilities dialog and disk space calculation in SFTP

Tags: sftp, winscp

`SFTP` servers can expose disk space utilization for a `device` - a volume or disk, by either implementing the `space-available` extension or by `OpenSSH` proprietary `statvfs@openssh.com` capability.

While connecting to `Bitvise` `SFTP` server, which is not an `OpenSSH`server using `WinSCP`, and by checking the `capabilities` dialog on `WinSCP` it says the server supports -

> statvfs@openssh.com="2"

This led to some confusion, I am not sure what a value of `2` here indicates. Also, does this mean that `BitVise` implements the `OpenSSH` method of calculating size, and not `space-available`?

In the `space available` tab, I can see that the size has indeed been calculated, but has it been calculated using `statvfs` or `space-available`?

On the off-chance (probably none) that a server implements both, perhaps to pander to more clients maybe, which one would be used by `WinSCP` for this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While connecting to `Bitvise` `SFTP` server, which is not an `OpenSSH` server using `WinSCP`, and by checking the `capabilities` dialog on `WinSCP` it says the server supports -
>
> > statvfs@openssh.com="2"

In general the meaning of value after `=` is specific to the extension. This particular extension uses the value to announce a version of the extension implemented by the server. The version 2 is the only version that was ever in use.

---

> Also, does this mean that `BitVise` implements the `OpenSSH` method of calculating size, and not `space-available`?

Bitvise implements both extensions. Though for some reasons, it does not announce a support for the `space-available` (so you won't see it in the list in WinSCP).

---

> On the off-chance (probably none) that a server implements both, perhaps to pander to more clients maybe, which one would be used by `WinSCP` for this calculation?

WinSCP prefers the `space-available`.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.